# Ошибка при подключении к базе данных PostgreSQL Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

При подключении к базе даных возникает следующая ошибка:

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError
```

код:

```
db_name = "Password_Vault"
db_user = 'postgres'
db_password = master_password
db_host = '127.0.0.1'
connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname=db_name, user=db_user, password=db_password, host=db_host)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db_name = 'super_tlgrm_bot'
db_user = 'bot'
db_password = 'bot'
db_host = '10.10.10.8'

psycopg2.connect(dbname=db_name, user=db_user, password=db_password, host=db_host)
```

[Учебник](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial)

Comment: Возникла следующая ошибка: psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "10.10.10.8", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)                                                                                                                             Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Comment: почему вы используете хост из примера? подставьте свои данные.

Comment: обновил код, ошибка всё та же

Comment: где у вас расположена база? какая ОС?

Comment: Windows. на порту 5432

Comment: если вы используете pgAdmin под Windows, попробуйте указать хост как localhost. а так же проверьте запущена ли служба/приложение pgadmin